# Text above and below header rule, hanging header text

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I'm trying to make a header on every page with text above and below the header rule, so that it looks something like this:

```
                                  header text above line
--------------------------------------------------------
                                  header text below line

[body of page]
```

Is this possible with `fancyhdr`? Or is there another way to do this?

I realize this may not be aesthetically pleasing, but I'm trying to emulate another document (not made with LaTeX).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, with fancyhdr:

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[LE,LO]{~\\\hrulefill\\~}
\fancyhead[CE,CO]{~\\\hrulefill\\~}
\fancyhead[RE,RO]{text above\\\hrulefill\\text below}
```

If desired, switch left and right. You will need to play with the headheight and the line skips in the header, and related dimensions.

Comment: This almost works. I end up with two horizontal lines, but I can remove the default one with `\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}`, and then I get the desired result. Thanks!

Comment: Right! You need to remove the default line. When I use fancyhdr, I start by zeroing or emptying everything and building up from there.

Answer (score 2):

You can set one header item using a `tabular` with a single `p`aragraph column that is the width of `\textwidth`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr,lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove header rule
\fancyhead[C]{%
  \begin{tabular}{ @{} p{\textwidth} @{} }
    \hfill Header text above line \\
    \hline
    \hfill Header text below line
  \end{tabular}}
\setlength{\headheight}{24.4pt}% Should be at least 24.4pt

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with `titleps`, a `tabular` environment  and `booktabs`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titleps}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, graphicx}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
\newpagestyle{mine}{\renewcommand\arraystretch{0.5}%
\sethead[][\begin{tabular}{@{}>{\raggedright\small\arraybackslash}p{\textwidth}@{}}header text above line\\\midrule header text below line\end{tabular}][]%
{}{\begin{tabular}{@{}>{\raggedleft\small\arraybackslash}p{\textwidth}@{}}header text above line\\\midrule header text below line\end{tabular}}{}
\setfoot{}{\thepage}{}
}
\pagestyle{mine}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a very interesting question and I would like to provide a comprehensive solution for document class `article`. This solution uses the packages `geometry`, `fancyhdr`, `pgf`, `scrextend` and `textpos`, it looks complicated at the beginning, but trust me, it is nice and **clean** and do not require adjustment even when you **change page geometry**.

The usage of the packages are, `geometry` is used to setup the page geometry, `fancyhdr` is used to produce the header, `pgf` is used to define length, `scrextend` is used to find out if current page is an even page or odd page, and finally `textpos` is used to place the text.

I also added text block at the top left corner.

Here is the code

```latex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[UTF8]{article}

\usepackage[b4paper, twoside]{geometry}
%% you can set page to be 'a4paper' or 'c5paper' or 'legalpaper' or whatever provided by 'geometry', no other adjustment is needed
%% even and odd page are set to have different margin size, you can set margin size to be equal by removing 'twoside', no other adjustment is needed
\usepackage{lipsum} %% generate random texts

\usepackage{fancyhdr} %% produce header

\usepackage{pgf} %% define length
\usepackage[absolute, overlay]{textpos} %% put text blocks at absolute position
\usepackage{scrextend} %% check if current page is even or odd

\pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\texttop}{1.0 in + \voffset + \topmargin + \headheight + \tabcolsep}
%% this is the very top of the body

\pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\textrightodd}{1.0 in + \oddsidemargin + \hoffset + \textwidth}
%% this is the right edge of the body for odd page
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\textrighteven}{1.0 in + \evensidemargin + \hoffset + \textwidth}
%% this is the right edge of the body for even page
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\textleftodd}{1.0 in + \oddsidemargin + \hoffset}
%% this is the left edge of the body for odd page
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\textlefteven}{1.0 in + \evensidemargin + \hoffset}
%% this is the left edge of the body for even page

\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1.0 pt}
%% set the unit used by 'textpos' to be 'pt' because the length returned by 'pdf' macros are in 'pt'

\pagestyle{fancy} %% set up page header
\lhead{left head}
\chead{center head}
\rhead{page \thepage}
\cfoot{}

\begin{document}

\title{title}
\date{\today}
\author{author}

\ifthispageodd{\textblockorigin{\textleftodd}{\texttop}}{\textblockorigin{\textlefteven}{\texttop}}
%% set the origin used by 'textpos' at top left of page for even and odd pages differently
\pgfmathwidth{"note for page \thepage"}
%% store the length of wanted text into '\pgfmathresult'
\begin{textblock}{\pgfmathresult}[0, 0](0, 0)
%% '[0, 0]' sets top left corner of text block to be used as anchor point, '(0, 0)' sets the anchor point right at the origin of 'textpos'
\noindent
note for page \thepage
\end{textblock}

\ifthispageodd{\textblockorigin{\textrightodd}{\texttop}}{\textblockorigin{\textrighteven}{\texttop}}
%% set the origin used by 'textpos' at top right of page for even and odd pages differently
\pgfmathwidth{"note for page \thepage"}
\begin{textblock}{\pgfmathresult}[1, 0](0, 0)
%% '[1, 0]' sets top right corner of text block to be used as anchor point, '(0, 0)' sets the anchor point right at the origin of 'textpos'
\noindent
note for page \thepage
\end{textblock}

\maketitle

\thispagestyle{fancy}

\lipsum[6]

\newpage

\ifthispageodd{\textblockorigin{\textleftodd}{\texttop}}{\textblockorigin{\textlefteven}{\texttop}}
\pgfmathwidth{"note for page \thepage"}
\begin{textblock}{\pgfmathresult}[0, 0](0, 0)
\noindent
note for page \thepage
\end{textblock}

\ifthispageodd{\textblockorigin{\textrightodd}{\texttop}}{\textblockorigin{\textrighteven}{\texttop}}
\pgfmathwidth{"note for page \thepage"}
\begin{textblock}{\pgfmathresult}[1, 0](0, 0)
\noindent
note for page \thepage
\end{textblock}

\lipsum[2]

\newpage

\ifthispageodd{\textblockorigin{\textleftodd}{\texttop}}{\textblockorigin{\textlefteven}{\texttop}}
\pgfmathwidth{"note for page \thepage"}
\begin{textblock}{\pgfmathresult}[0, 0](0, 0)
\noindent
note for page \thepage
\end{textblock}

\ifthispageodd{\textblockorigin{\textrightodd}{\texttop}}{\textblockorigin{\textrighteven}{\texttop}}
\pgfmathwidth{"note for page \thepage"}
\begin{textblock}{\pgfmathresult}[1, 0](0, 0)
\noindent
note for page \thepage
\end{textblock}

\lipsum[3]

\newpage

\ifthispageodd{\textblockorigin{\textleftodd}{\texttop}}{\textblockorigin{\textlefteven}{\texttop}}
\pgfmathwidth{"note for page \thepage"}
\begin{textblock}{\pgfmathresult}[0, 0](0, 0)
\noindent
note for page \thepage
\end{textblock}

\ifthispageodd{\textblockorigin{\textrightodd}{\texttop}}{\textblockorigin{\textrighteven}{\texttop}}
\pgfmathwidth{"note for page \thepage"}
\begin{textblock}{\pgfmathresult}[1, 0](0, 0)
\noindent
note for page \thepage
\end{textblock}

\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

here is what is produced

[image: text block]

For the page geometry, you can refer to this figure

[image: layout]