# Title spreading across two pages; different title second page onwards

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I'd like to create a LaTeX template that will yield the following PDF output:

[image]

I tried various methods, but still I failed to **spread the title header across the 2-page layout** as shown above. I'd also like to add a name, course title and date below the straight line as shown above, and the page number to appear in the middle at the bottom (again ignoring the global two-page layout setting).

---

From **second page onwards**, I'd like to have a different title header, with the name on the left, the title of the handout in the middle, and the date on the right, as shown below:

[image]

I'm new to LaTeX, and so any help or advice would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Considering the position of the page numbers, isn't this rather a two-column layout on single pages in landscape format?

Comment: Thanks, Jasper. I still have an issue with creating the title header exactly as shown in the first page, where some text appears above the straight line and some other text appears below it. Is there any suggestion how this could be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know where you store the title, the author and the date, hence I created new macros for this that also allow for short versions of the title and the author's name. But of course you can adjust it to your liking. The use of the tabular environment is based on suggestions in answers to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/330241/47927).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[landscape, a4paper, twocolumn, margin=3cm, columnsep=2cm,
    headheight=1.5cm, top=3.5cm, headsep=.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, afterpage}

\newcommand{\mytitle}[2][]{%
    \newcommand{\myshorttitle}{#1}%
    \newcommand{\mylongtitle}{#2}%
}

\newcommand{\myauthor}[2][]{%
    \newcommand{\myshortauthor}{#1}%
    \newcommand{\mylongauthor}{#2}%
}

\newcommand{\mynumberdate}[2]{%
    \newcommand{\mynumber}{#1}%
    \newcommand{\mydate}{#2}%
}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[L]{%
    \begin{tabular}{ @{} p{.333\textwidth} 
                     @{} >{\centering}p{.333\textwidth} 
                     @{} >{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{.333\textwidth} @{} }
        \myshortauthor & \myshorttitle & \mydate \\ \midrule
    \end{tabular}%
}
\fancypagestyle{fancyfirstpage}{%
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
    \fancyhead[L]{%
        \begin{tabular}{ @{} p{.5\textwidth} 
                         @{} >{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{.5\textwidth} @{} }
            \textbf{\mylongtitle} & \\ \midrule
            \mylongauthor & \mynumber \\ & \mydate 
        \end{tabular}%
    }
}    
\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{fancyfirstpage}

\mytitle[Meaning of Life]{An Introduction to the Meaning of Life}
\myauthor[Smith]{Mary Smith}
\mynumberdate{PHIL1001}{1 January 2021}

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: If you want 'clean', you can define `\fancypagestyle{firstpage}{...}` and use `\thispagestyle{firstpage}`

Comment: Thanks. I edited the example (almost) accordingly.

Comment: @JasperHabicht You are leaking a lot of spaces. Lucky you that TeX gobbles them all. ;)

Comment: @AndreasMatthias Well, where would you remove spaces then (or did I not understand you correctly)? I thought adding some space would help structuring the code and won't do any harm, since TeX skips most of the spaces anyways.

Comment: @JasperHabicht Try `x\mytitle{test}x` and you will see the spaces. ;) It's a good idea to take care of spaces before they bite you. Afterwards it can be very hard to find them in the code.

Comment: Oh, there you mean! Indeed! Thank you for pointing this out. I edited my answer.